# How to apply a 1D filter (CSF) to an image?

Tags: image-processing, filters, fourier-transform, convolution

I am facing the following problem:
I have an image and a contrast sentivity function (CSF). The CSF is a function defined in the frequency domain and it is just a band-pass filter. The problem is that it is a 1D filter so I do not know how to apply it to the Fourier transform of the image.

I thought about creating a 2D filter based on the revolution around the zero frequency of the 1D filter but I do not know if it is mathematically correct or if it is the common procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is take your 1D filter column vector, call it $x$, and create a 2D filter with $xx^T$.  The result of this outer product (column vector times row vector) is a matrix that you can use to do element-wise multiplication with the 2D Fourier transform of the image.

Comment: I am sorry. I accepted your answer but I realized that it is not what I wanted. If you do the outer product you do not get the revolution of the 1D function but only in the quartes. Nevertheless, I give you up vote for the idea (EDIT: It seems I am not allowed :S).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to do... it sounds like you want to rotate a vector in a polar coordinate system?

Comment: That's it, but with outer product you do not get an exact rotation. For example, the outer product of the function $y=x^2$ defined over the region $[-1,1]$ is not a paraboloid of revolution.